# ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE when chaincode is invoked using node.js SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Steps followed:

**1. Started a Hyperledger Fabric network with 1 organization,1 Peer,1
   couch db and 1 CA**

**2. Created channel**

```
docker exec command -e"CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
```

**3. Joined peer to the channel using docker exec command**

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
```

**4. Installed chaincode**

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" cli peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n fabcar -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[""]}' -P "AND ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"
```

**5. Started the client**

**6. Used node SDK to enroll and register a user**

**7. Ran invoke.js [from fabcar example] to initledger with 10 cars**

**8. The invoke query throws ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE error.Please note that endorsement policy is set as "AND"** [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KXoP.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your endorsement policy requires a peer from Org1 and a peer from Org2 to endorse the transaction.  Given you are only running a single peer from Org1, there is no way to satisfy this endorsement policy.

Try setting the endorsement policy to

`-P "AND ('Org1MSP.member')"`

or adding a peer from Org2 to the channel and install the chaincode.